# how to get a excel cell values to variables in c# coded step

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I am trying to get the values of excel sheet into variables in c#.
In a coded step I am doing

```
 string myPath = @"C:\Users\Monica\Desktop\ExcelTest.xlsx";
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);

        //select the correct worksheet

        Excel.Worksheet demoWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

        excelApp.Visible = false;
```

I want to do something like this. I want to get value of a cell to a variable to be used later in the testscript.

```
          //string sample= demoWorksheet.Cells[1, 3].value
```

Can someone please give me some pointers on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use get_Range to get cell Value.

```
var value = demoWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").Value2;
```